# My .txt files lag when their text is loaded - Can saving to Firebase and loading from there speed this up?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have .txt files that are only read on my app and are saved under the Content folder locally. There is a 2 sec lag in simulator when I load a .txt file for reading. I'm trying to understand if Firebase can help me speed this up.

I've seen Firebase tutorials on how to save data written as a result of an action on your app, like game scores or images even. Could I save the .txt files in firebase instead of locally and then retrieve them when tapped on the app - would this speed up loading of the .txt files?

Answer (score 1):

No saving files to firebase storage will not speed up the load time instead it will increase the time since now network is involved in it. Firebase storage is used to keep the data persisted even if the local data gets deleted.

You need to optimize the file read by dividing the file in some sub files so that you can speed up the file read.

Answer (score 1):

No, save the file to the Firebase storage not help you.

You can save the content of the file into the firebase database and retrieve and store locally it only if its content is changed from the last time using a version number. This can help you.

Is the lag in the load or parse? If it is in the parsing you can try to use an xml instead of txt, it is more performing.